# Unable to play video/display image in lwc

Tags: lightning-web-components

I'm trying to play a video and display image in the lwc. I'm fetching the video and image url which includes a static url + token(fetched through integration) from backend method. However, it doesn't show both video and image on the component at all. Does it have something to do with values being set in connectedcallback?

HTML:

```
<div>
            <img src={sThumbnailUrl}/>
        </div>
        <div class="fancy-border">
            <div>Video</div>
            <video autoplay>
                <source src={sVideoUrl} type="video/mp4"/>
            </video>
            <button onclick={play}>Play</button>
            <button onclick={pause}>Pause</button>
        </div>
```

JS:

```
@track sFMCToken = '';
    @track sImageUrl = '';
    sBrowser = '';
    sVideoUrl = '';
    sPlayButton = '';
    sPauseButton = '';
    sThumbnailUrl;
    sPlay = play_pause+'/Images/playbutton.png';
    sPause = play_pause+'/Images/pausebutton.png';
    //sVideoUrl = 'https://d3fka592uu6tyf.cloudfront.net/raw_videos/b1dcc5a4-5c45-4117-b0c8-3568cd6b2f88.mp4';
    connectedCallback(){
        this.fetchFMCToken().then(res=>{
            this.sVideoUrl = res.sVideoUrl;
            this.sThumbnailUrl = res.sThumbnailUrl;
            this.sPlayButton = play_button;
            this.sPauseButton = pause_button;

            // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
            console.log('sThumbnailUrl',this.sThumbnailUrl);
            // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
            console.log('sVideoUrl',this.sVideoUrl);
            // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
            console.log('sPlayButton',this.sPlayButton);
            // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
            console.log('sPauseButton',this.sPauseButton);
        })
    }
    getBrowser() {
        navigator.sayswho = (function() {
            var ua = navigator.userAgent,
                tem,
                M = ua.match(/(opera|chrome|safari|firefox|msie|trident(?=\/))\/?\s*(\d+)/i) || [];
            if (/trident/i.test(M[1])) {
                tem = /\brv[ :]+(\d+)/g.exec(ua) || [];
                return 'IE ' + (tem[1] || '');
            }
            if (M[1] === 'Chrome') {
                tem = ua.match(/\b(OPR|Edge)\/(\d+)/);
                if (tem != null) return tem.slice(1).join(' ').replace('OPR', 'Opera');
            }
            M = M[2] ? [ M[1], M[2] ] : [ navigator.appName, navigator.appVersion, '-?' ];
            if ((tem = ua.match(/version\/(\d+)/i)) != null) M.splice(1, 1, tem[1]);
            return M.join(' ');
        })();
        if(navigator.sayswho.toUpperCase().includes('CHROME'))
            this.sBrowser = 'Chrm';
        else if(navigator.sayswho.toUpperCase().includes('FIREFOX'))    
            this.sBrowser = 'FFox';
        else if(navigator.sayswho.toUpperCase().includes('TRIDENT') || navigator.sayswho.toUpperCase().includes('IE') || navigator.sayswho.toUpperCase().includes('EDGE'))    
            this.sBrowser = 'IE';    
        else if(navigator.sayswho.toUpperCase().includes('IPHONE') || navigator.sayswho.toUpperCase().includes('SAFARI'))    
            this.sBrowser = 'IE';    
        return this.sBrowser;
    }
    fetchFMCToken(){
        this.getBrowser();
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
        console.log('Browser info to send to backend : ' ,this.sBrowser);
        return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
            FMC_TOKEN({sBrowserContext:this.sBrowser})
            .then(result=>{
                this.sFMCToken = result;
                this.sError = null;
                // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
                console.log('result : ',result);
                resolve(result);
            })
            .catch(error=>{
                this.sError = error;
                this.sFMCToken = null;
                reject(error);
            })
        })


    }
    get isPlaying() {
        const player = this.template.querySelector('video');
        return player !== null && player.paused === false;
    }

    play() {
        const player = this.template.querySelector('video');
        // the player might not be in the DOM just yet
        if (player) {
            player.play();
        }
    }

    pause() {
        const player = this.template.querySelector('video');
        if (player) {
            // the player might not be in the DOM just yet
            player.pause();
        }
    }

    // private method for computed value
    get videoType() {
        return 'video/' + this.sVideoUrl.split('.').pop();
    }
```

console prints the url's for **sThumbnailUrl** and **sVideoUrl** but nothing shows up for the video tag and the image isn't rendered too. Any idea why this might be happening?